# MySQL Server 8.0. my.ini file editing. To prevent MySQL Server from connecting to Internet

Tags: mysql, database

I want to install MySQL Server 8.0 on my desktop computer. The operating system is Windows 10 Home. I want to prevent MySQL Server from connecting to the Internet. I assume that MySQL Server is connected to the following ports: port - 3306, x protocol port - 33060. I don't want to connect to MySQL Server via TCP/IP. In the my.ini file there are subsections [client] and [mysql].

How do I need to edit [client] subsection?

```
[client]

# pipe=

# socket=MYSQL

port=3306
```

---

How do I need to edit [mysqld] subsection?

```
[mysqld]

# The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT below.
# skip-networking
# enable-named-pipe
# shared-memory

# shared-memory-base-name=MYSQL

# The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
# socket=MYSQL

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
```

Comment: *I don't want to connect to MySQL Server via TCP/IP.* Using `port=3306` without using both pipe and socket means you WILL connect to server via TCP/IP. To disable external connections set `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Akina

Thank you, Akina.

Where I need to add instruction

bind-address = 127.0.0.1

in [mysqld] subsection?

Comment: As [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html) claims *mysqld reads options from the [mysqld] and [server] groups. mysqld_safe reads options from the [mysqld], [server], [mysqld_safe], and [safe_mysqld] groups. mysql.server reads options from the [mysqld] and [mysql.server] groups.* So the only section used by all possible processes is [mysqld], and bind-address setting must be placed into it. But I recommend to set this parameter from the command line - when you need to alter this setting it will be more simple than edit ini-file.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, Akina.

I recommend to set this parameter from the command line - when you need to alter this setting it will be more simple than edit ini-file

I undersand you. I want to try both variants.

mysqld group will be:

[mysqld]

bind-address="127.0.0.1"
bind-address = ::1

# The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT below.
# skip-networking
# enable-named-pipe
# shared-memory

# shared-memory-base-name=MYSQL

# The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
# socket=MYSQL

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306

Yes?

Comment: I am not sure that more than one *bind-address* parameter is allowed in your MySQL version... is it 8.0.13 or higher?